# flutter response always same

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I was trying to get a response from api(i made this with node js and mongo db)

When I check the api with postman it gives me random outputs for different emails

Here for this email it give me correct output in postman

[image]

The problem is when I call this api in flutter it always gives me "new user" for every email I try

This is the code I used in flutter

```
class FbLoginService {
  static Future<bool> FbAuth(body) async {
    final stest = {"email": "a@a.com"};
    final response = await http.post(
      'http://example.com/api/user/loginwithfb',
      body: stest
    );

    final data = response.body;
    print(data);

    // final temp = jsonEncode(data);

    // Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(data);
    // print(user['loginstatus']);

    // if (user['loginstatus'] == 'newuser') {
    //   return true;
    // } else {
    //   return false;
    // }
    return true;  
  }
}
```

This always gives me this out put

[image]

Comment: There is no question in your post, and very little code to work with. Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And we cannot see your mongodb code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that postman send this request with `Content-Type':'application/json'` header

So adding that header to my code solved the problem and then it worked like a charm

```
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
final response = await http.post(
      'http://example.com/api/user/loginwithfb',
      body: stest,
      headers:headers
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postman you are sending a string as the body that looks like JSON.

in Dart you are passing a `Map<String, String>` as `body`, so the client will url form encode that.

To make your Dart code behave the same as Postman change:

```
  body: stest,
```

to:

```
  body: json.encode(stest),
```